# Custom ordering in UI List

Tags: python, interface

If somebody is versed in UI lists code, can you help me with custom ordering? It seems impossible. I want items sorted by custom property integer value, instead of name and can't get it to work.

I'm using

```
ordered = bpy.types.UI_UL_list.sort_items_helper(items, key=lambda item: item.get("custom_property", 0), reverse=False)
```

And its not working. I'm getting this error

```
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\startup\bl_ui\__init__.py", line 221, in sort_items_helper
    sort_data.sort(key=key, reverse=reverse)
AttributeError: bpy_prop_collection: attribute "sort" not found
```

Comment: What type is *items*? It seems to be a [bpy_prop_collection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection.html) that has no sort() function. This is the reason for the error. -  *items* should be a list of tuples according to https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UI_UL_list.html and *sort_items_helper* returns a list (... of tuples? of indexes?). Try *...sort_items_helper(items.items() ...*. I guess, you need to create a new collection from the result list then.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort items in the UIList using the rather convoluted [bpy.types.UIList.filter_items](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UIList.html#bpy.types.UIList.filter_items).

eg

```
class YOUR_UI_LIST(bpy.types.UIList):
    def draw_item(
        self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname
    ):
        layout.label(text=item.name)

    def filter_items(self, context, data, propname):
        items = getattr(data, propname)
        items_sorted = sorted(items, key=lambda it: it.get("custom_property", 0))
        filter_neworder = [items.index(item_sorted) for item_sorted in items_sorted]

        filter_flags = [self.bitflag_filter_item] * len(items)
        return filter_flags, filter_neworder
```

If you want to hide certain items depending on context using `filter_flags`, instead of `self.bitflag_filter_item` set the item index to 1 for example.

eg if you want to hide the first item :

```
filter_flags = [self.bitflag_filter_item] * len(items)
filter_flags[0] = 1  # This will hide item index 0
```

`filter_neworder` is a list that contains the new indices for each item in the list.

eg for a list with 2 items, if item at index 0 is sorted at index 1 and item at index 1 is sorted at index 0, (reverse list) `filter_neworder = (1, 0)`.